# First-order formalism General relativity

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I am trying to find the stress energy tensor for an ideal fluid from a first-order formalism. My matter lagrangian is $\int d^4 \sqrt{-g} [g^{\mu\nu} \partial_{\mu} \theta \partial_{\nu} \theta - V(\theta)]$ where my scalar field $\theta$ is only time dependent. I was able to convert it to $\int *(d\theta)(d\theta) - \frac{1}{4!}\int \epsilon_{IJKL}e^{I} \wedge e^{J} \wedge e^{K} \wedge e^{L} V(\theta) $. But I am getting $\frac{\dot{\theta}^{2}}{2} - V({\theta})$ for both pressure and density instead of $\frac{\dot{\theta}^{2}}{2} + V({\theta})$ and $\frac{\dot{\theta}^{2}}{2} - V({\theta})$.

Comment: Please provide details of you calculation. Since the term $\frac{1}{4!}\int \epsilon_{IJKL}e^{I} \wedge e^{J} \wedge e^{K} \wedge e^{L} V(\theta)$ is Cosmological Constant-like, it SHOULD give the correct pressure and density with the opposite sign.